# dplyr filter return all from a data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I have a selectInput function, and when the users select "All Universities" I want dplyr::filter to return all values instead. It's being passed a dataframe so dplry::if_else errors out.

```
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("university", 
                     "Select University",
                     choices = list("All Universities" = "all", "UAA" = "uaa", "UAF" = "uaf", "UAS" = "uas"),
                     multiple = F
          ),
        width = 2),
```

and here is my shiny table output function

```
   output$headcountTable <- function(){
     enroll_report |>
      dplyr::filter(struc_uni == input$university)|>
      dplyr::select(-struc_uni) |>
      dplyr::select(-struc_code) |>
      kbl(booktabs = T,
        col.names = c("Campus", 
                     "Fall 2021", 
                     "Fall 2022",
                     "Change",
                     "%",
                     "Fall 2021", 
                     "Fall 2022",
                     "Change",
                     "%"),
        caption = "holder text") |>
      add_header_above(c("", "Headcount" = 4, "Credit Hours" = 4)) |>
      kable_styling("striped", 
               full_width = T, 
               position = "left", 
               font_size = 12)
   }
```

Comment: Try `filter({if(input$university == "all"){TRUE}else{struc_uni == input$university}})`.

Comment: This worked and I am going to keep it in my back pocket since I know I'll need it again in this project! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an "in-line" version of the solution by John Manacup. It looks a little weird because you are using the `|>` pipe, which does not have a place holder, so I define one using the `()()` structure and the `\()` anonymous function.

```r
output$headcountTable <- function(){
     enroll_report |>
      (\(d) if(input$university == "all") d 
       else dplyr::filter(d, struc_uni == input$university))() |>
      dplyr::select(-struc_uni) |>
      dplyr::select(-struc_code) |>
      kbl(booktabs = T,
        col.names = c("Campus", 
                     "Fall 2021", 
                     "Fall 2022",
                     "Change",
                     "%",
                     "Fall 2021", 
                     "Fall 2022",
                     "Change",
                     "%"),
        caption = "holder text") |>
      add_header_above(c("", "Headcount" = 4, "Credit Hours" = 4)) |>
      kable_styling("striped", 
               full_width = T, 
               position = "left", 
               font_size = 12)
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can isolate the code that filters it and check it using a simple `if`.

**NOTE: this only works if such case is isolated.**

```
if(input$university != "all"){
    enroll_report <- enroll_report %>% 
      dplyr::filter(struct_uni == input$university)
}

enroll_report |>
  dplyr::select(-struc_uni) |>
  dplyr::select(-struc_code) |>
  kbl(booktabs = T,
  col.names = c("Campus", 
                "Fall 2021", 
                "Fall 2022",
                "Change",
                "%",
                "Fall 2021", 
                "Fall 2022",
                "Change",
                "%"),
  caption = "holder text") |>
  add_header_above(c("", "Headcount" = 4, "Credit Hours" = 4)) |>
  kable_styling("striped", 
            full_width = T, 
            position = "left", 
            font_size = 12)
```

Comment: Is is a very poor solution. You're overwriting the original source data. (In this particularly case, it's fine because the question author is calling within a function and it won't assign into the global environment, but still). What happens when the user wants to switch between universities?